# How to traverse two arrays simultaneously using only one for loop in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, arrays

I want to traverse two arrays simultaneously using only one for loop.

```
# For notifications section
@notifications=[]
@challenges=Challenge.where("to_id=? and activity_id=?" ,current_user.id,@activity.id)

@challenges.each do |k|
@match_results=MatchResult.where("challenge_id=? and result_confirmation_status=?" ,@challenges[k].id,1)
end

@challenge=@challenge.reverse
@match_results=@match_results.reverse
```

Then I want to merge these two arrays using "update_at" field means the record which is latest updated should be saved first in an array.

Comment: I do not see any loops in the code? can you better explain how you want to use the results in your views. That might help resolving it.

Comment: There appears to be a few things wrong here. `Challenge.where("to_id=? and activity_id=?" ,current_user.id,@activity.id)` is returning an 'array'. In the next line you use `@challenge.id` This should give you an `undefined method \`id\` for *snip*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@notifications=[]
@challenges=Challenge.where("to_id=? and activity_id=?" ,current_user.id,@activity.id)
@match_results=[]
@challenges.each do |k|
@match_results=@match_results<<MatchResult.where("challenge_id=? and result_confirmation_status=?" ,k.id,1)
end
@challenges=@challenges.reverse
@match_results=@match_results.reverse

@notifications=(@match_results+@challenges).sort_by(&:updated_at)
@notifications=@notifications.reverse
puts @notifications.inspect
```